# Why does the create event get triggered for previously created CRDs when my kubernetes controller is restarted with controller-runtime?

Tags: go, kubernetes, client-go

I am trying to understand the [controller-runtime](https://pkg.go.dev/sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime) framework for reconciling custom resources in my k8s cluster. I observe that create event gets triggered each time my pod running the controller gets restarted.

When I set up watchers on a CRD type and start or restart a pod running the controller, I notice the create event gets triggered for each of my CRDs in the cluster. Is this normal behaviour? How do I ensure that the CRD is only reconciled upon the first create only. I do not wish to get the create event upon pod failures/restarts.